# What would be an alternative of "poke" to German English speakers?

Tags: translation, english-to-german, english, informal

I'm facing a problem quite often when speaking in English with Germans. I'm used to say in some situations "Poke you later..." or "Poke me when you're done with this...".

I know that better ways exist to say that in English but I would like to know what would be my options to not be misunderstood by them when they translate that.

One of the examples of the translation from English would be "stoßen".

Comment: This is very uncommon in English, I've never heard anyone can "Poke you later", most people would say "See you later".

Comment: im asking because im not native english speaker, thats why so i often say that, but ive heard many natives saying that already...

Comment: Totally depends on context. "Sprich mich später nochmal darauf an." "Frag mich nachher nochmal." "Sag mir Bescheid, wenn du damit fertig bist."

Comment: This remembers me of the old, past days of the Orkut Glory and it's Budypokes...

Comment: @MarceloFilho I'm a native English speaker, I don't even speak german, I just wanted to point out, that most english speakers wouldn't under stand what your mean.

Comment: As the existing answers interpreted your question differently, there clearly is some need of clarification: Are you looking for an English or a German word? In the former case, I strongly suggest that you ask on [ell.se].

Answer (score 5):

Although I fear that your usage of the English word **to poke** is at least, say, *uncommon*, I have to place a bit of a guess on what you might *think* this means in English -the best way for a close to literal translation to German would maybe be *jemanden anhauen*.

> Wenn du mal wieder Hilfe brauchst, kannst du mich ja einfach anhauen.
>
> Ich hab' den um 'ne Fluppe angehauen, aber er hatte keine mehr.

Note this is a colloquial expression.

Comment: *I poked him for a ziggy…*? Not quite the same nuance methinks. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Close to the English *to poke* is the German *anstupsen* that also can be used in the same context:

> Darf ich Dich wegen der fehlenden Bilder morgen nochmal anstupsen?
>   Stups mich einfach an, sobald Du weißt, wie die Farbe werden soll.

Comment: https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/stupsen#/media/File:USMC-091024-M-0902C-005.jpg

Comment: "anstupsen" is a sort of technical term for the process of contacting in one spcific social media site. I'd not use these formulations outside of that context

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: Funny idea, no longer to use a word in a generic way because some (a few?) consider it as a *technical term*.

Comment: I have never heard "anstubsen" being used to mean anything else than either direct physical contact or a social media message (and would be *very* surprised if someone said what's in your answer to me)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I believe "poke" has a similar [social media origin](https://www.facebook.com/help/219967728031249).

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest

> "Ich melde mich später..."

and

> "Melde dich, wenn du damit fertig bist ..."